# HTTP_OAuth installation help

Tags: php, xampp

I got this error.

Warning: require_once(HTTP/OAuth.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplegeo-Services_SimpleGeo-7e5516f\Services\SimpleGeo.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'HTTP/OAuth.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplegeo-Services_SimpleGeo-7e5516f\Services\SimpleGeo.php on line 25

How can I install pear or HTTP/OAuth.php I don't have an idea how can I install it. I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this:

```
pear install HTTP_OAuth
```

good places to start looking for answers are

1. http://php.net/oauth
2. http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.setup.php
3. http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth/

Answer (score 1):

Also check this :  http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/7700/post/1-Painless-OAuth-with-PHP.html

Is seems to be a simpler way to use OAuth protocol very transparently.